# Error in JCL DFSORT

Tags: jcl, dfsort

I would like to ask for help regarding this JCL... I can't seem to get it working. I'm running this on mainframe. I get RC 16.

```
//X544582Z  JOB (T,92958888P),                      
//          'N=TSO.X544582',                        
//          CLASS=S,                                
//          MSGCLASS=H,                             
//          MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                         
//          REGION=32M,                             
//          NOTIFY=&SYSUID                          
//*         TYPRUN=SCAN                             
//JOBLIB    DD DSN=X544582.LOADLIB1,DISP=SHR        
//COPY      EXEC PGM=SORT                           
//SYSOUT    DD   SYSOUT=*                           
//SORTIN    DD DSN=X544582.CMIGRATE.INPUT01,DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=X544582.CMIGRATE.INPUT02,DISP=SHR
//SYSIN     DD *                                    
  OPTION COPY                                       
  OUTREC BUILD=(1,1172,TRAN=ATOE)                   
/*                                                  
//
```

Comment: You need to included the full sysout from the step which failed. Looking at that, we may not know what problem is generated. The sysout will also tell us the size of your input records.

Comment: RC=16 just means there is something wrong, which SORT can't deal with.

Comment: Interested to know which it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC=16 just means there is something wrong, which SORT can't deal with.

Guessing:

1. Your input is VB, and you should have:

   OPTION COPY
     OUTREC BUILD=(5,TRAN=ATOE)

   The `5` says "from position 5 to the end of the current record".
2. Your input is FB, and your record-length is less than 1172.